# Using free google api plan for Bitrix24

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, bitrix

recently my company started using Bitrix24 as an intranet portal. Our employees use google drive and calendar synchronization between their google accounts (private ones, not gsuite). Few days ago I received an email from google:

[image: Email content]

We have contacted Bitrix24 support, but they could not give us any specifics with regards to this email and pointed out to contact google. Free google plans do not really have helpdesk support and point to sites like stackoverflow for help.

We do not really know what to do in this situation, as we have very little knowledge about google developer console. One of us just used his account to set up a project and provide OAuth to sync google accounts with bitrix24.

Answer (score 0):

Several months ago google started releasing security changes enacted to help ensure that users data is secure.   Due to this all developers with applications running risky scopes must apply for [application verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en)

The developer who has created this application, probably the same person who received that email must click the link and submit the application.   Once your project is approved you will not have any more issues.   I suggest you begin the process now as it may take sometime for you to compete the process.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I got one more question with regards to the request. There is a filed where you need to paste a link to privacy policy of the app that needs to be hosted on the domain. It is not like we really developed anything so what do we with that?